# Get Public IP from OCI Instance using OCI CLI

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How do I get public IP from an OCI instance with OCI CLI?

There is a command from the docs - `oci network public-ip get` but this expects parameters like --private-ip-id and -public-ip-id which also cannot be fetched using OCI CLI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [list-vnics](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/2.24.3/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/compute/instance/list-vnics.html)

```
oci compute instance list-vnics --instance-id <instance-ocid>
```

to list the interfaces for the instance. The interface details is a list and each entry contains the field "public-ip". You can use the following CLI command with jq to get the public IP address:

```
oci compute instance list-vnics --instance-id <instance-id> | jq -r '.data[]."public-ip"'
```

Comment: If you want to incorporate this into a scipt, the `oci` tool supports [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) queries, so you can run this:

```python
oci --raw-output --query 'data[0]."public-ip"' compute instance list-vnics --instance-id $I
```

And it will output just the IP address of the first VNIC without any JSON.